# combine SQL result with comma delimiter

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to combine **tags** from below query to be separated by comma delimiter:

SQL

```
select question.text,tag.text
from question
left join q_t on question.id = q_t.wall_id
left join tag on q_t.tag_id = tag.id
where question.id in (1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005) 
order by field(question.id,1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005)
```

current result:

```
text                         text
where is England?         Geography
where is England?         Continent
where is England?         general_knowledge
how many ...?             sport
how many ...?             Europe
```

requested result:

```
text                         text
where is England?         Geography,Continent,general_knowledge
how many ...?             sport,Europe
```

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) but there is a default limit constraint of 1024 characters to concatenate from the result and remaining data will be truncated however this limit can be increased by following manual but it has also a dependency on [*max_allowed_packet*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) too

```
select question.text,group_concat(tag.text)
from question
left join q_t on question.id = q_t.wall_id
left join tag on q_t.tag_id = tag.id
where question.id in (1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005) 
group by  question.text
order by field(question.id,1000001,1000002,1000003,1000004,1000005)
```